# Phonegap Contacts API returning null for all values except id and rowid

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried the phonegap contacts api navigator.contacts.find()

Contacts. length is showing 100+, but when all the object values are null except id and rowid

```
  {
        "id": "1654",
        "rawId": "1652",
        "displayName": null,
        "name": null,
        "nickname": null,
        "phoneNumbers": null,
        "emails": null,
        "addresses": null,
        "ims": null,
        "organizations": null,
        "birthday": null,
        "note": null,
        "photos": null,
        "categories": null,
        "urls": null
    },
    {
        "id": "1656",
        "rawId": "1653",
        "displayName": null,
        "name": null,
        "nickname": null,
        "phoneNumbers": null,
        "emails": null,
        "addresses": null,
        "ims": null,
        "organizations": null,
        "birthday": null,
        "note": null,
        "photos": null,
        "categories": null,
        "urls": null
    },
...
```

My code is

```
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter   = "";
    options.multiple = true;
    options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
    options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
    //var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName,      
    navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
    var fields       = ["*"];       
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

I'm new to phonegap, anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

please comment out this line:

```
//options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
```

here you specify that the results should only contain ids/rawIds

Answer (score 0):

Set :
`options.hasPhoneNumber = true;`

Then that should not be any issue.